# How to access app.config from blueprint outside of request (Flask, pluggable views)

Tags: python, flask

I would like to be able to access app.config from a Pluggable View class

What i have:
flask app, pluggable views, blueprints

```
from flask import current_app

# using pluggable views
class Router(MethodView):

  # applying flask_login.login_required to all methods
  # in the current class
  decorators = [flask_login.login_required]   

  def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

  def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

What i want:
(this does not work, as there's no app / request context, and current_app isn't set)

```
from flask import current_app


class Router(MethodView):

  # this does not work
  if current_app.config['LOGIN_REQUIRED']:       
    decorators = [flask_login.login_required]  

  def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

  def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your python code (as you might realize given it's 5 months later), not your flask code or flask.

When you set fields directly in a class like that, you're setting the static fields of the class. When a class is instatiated it 'inherits' the static fields. But they're not recalculated ever. To fix your problem with current_app not being set you can just do:

```py
from flask import current_app


class Router(MethodView):

  def __init__(self):
    login_required = current_app.config['LOGIN_REQUIRED']
    # other logic etc

  def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

  def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

And if you wanted to make it so you can access `login_required` in get and post, you would just set `self.login_required` in the constructor instead, as that would initialize an instance variable.

But you still can't change the decorators like that in flask. The reason why is because it doesn't convert the decorators at request time, it converts them when you call .as_view on the pluggable view. As we can see in the source file `flask/views.py`:

```py
class View(object):
  ...
  ...

      @classmethod
    def as_view(cls, name, *class_args, **class_kwargs):
        ...
        ...

        if cls.decorators:
            view.__name__ = name
            view.__module__ = cls.__module__
            for decorator in cls.decorators:
                view = decorator(view)
        ...
        ...
        return view
```

As you can see, it specifically accesses the static decorator list when it's converted into a view. So it doesn't matter what you do to it in the constructor, it has already created them.

If you need this functionality (I don't know why you'd need that in the first place?) then it would probably be best to implement it in your own decorator.